# Add \hrulefill in the toc at a specified position

Tags: table-of-contents

For a more visible separation between starred chapters, I would like to have a horizontal line (e.g., `\hrulefill`, or alternative) appearing in the table of contents at determined positions, in the MWE betweem the third and six chapter, maybe using `\addtocontents{toc}{}{}`. How could I do this ?

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

% Insert \hrulefill in the toc here

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\end{document}
```

Example here:

[image]

Comment: Using `\chapters*{}` ;-)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer Yes indeed, not very smart of me. I forgot that `\chapter*` does not go in the toc ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

% Insert \hrulefill in the toc here
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hrulefill\protect\leavevmode\par}

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\end{document}
```

Or better:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}{}}

\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: be aware that if the chapters are not in the main file, but are accessed with `\include{chaptern}` the application of `\addtocontents` will not take place until after that included chapter has been processed.  (in other words, the rule would appear between chapters 3 and 4.)  in such a case, the `\addtocontents` instruction should be included in that chapter file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I am aware of this -- the example however does not show anything of this special setup. Thanks nevertheless

Comment: should probably have posted the comment at the question.  so often it's assumed that `\include` can be substituted directly for `\chapter` and vice versa.  especially where a mwe is requested, this "simplification" is often applied, and it doesn't always work.

Comment: @barbara beeton Thanks a lot for the precision. I use the `\include{}` function quite often, but did not think that it would change anything here.